# Why did Jesus say "Get behind me, Satan! You are a stumbling block to me..." towards Peter?

Tags: matthew, jesus

Matthew 16:21 - 28.

> 21 From that time forth began Jesus to shew unto his disciples, how that he must go unto Jerusalem, and suffer many things of the elders and chief priests and scribes, and be killed, and be raised again the third day.
>
> 22 Then Peter took him, and began to rebuke him, saying, Be it far from thee, Lord: this shall not be unto thee.
>
> 23 **But he turned, and said unto Peter, Get thee behind me, Satan**: thou art an offence unto me: for thou savourest not the things that be of God, but those that be of men.
>
> 24 Then said Jesus unto his disciples, If any man will come after me, let him deny himself, and take up his cross, and follow me.
>
> 25 For whosoever will save his life shall lose it: and whosoever will lose his life for my sake shall find it.
>
> 26 For what is a man profited, if he shall gain the whole world, and lose his own soul? or what shall a man give in exchange for his soul?
>
> 27 For the Son of man shall come in the glory of his Father with his angels; and then he shall reward every man according to his works.
>
> 28 Verily I say unto you, There be some standing here, which shall not taste of death, till they see the Son of man coming in his kingdom. (KJV)

Peter is not Satan. Who is Jesus talking to and about?

Answer (score 5):

I think Jesus was talking to Peter himself and that he called him Satan metaphorically. Such an interpretation would correspond with Jeremiah 30:9 and Ezekiel 37:24 where the Messiah is called "David". Obviously the Messiah wasn't literally the David of the OT resurrected as Jesus of Nazareth. But Jeremiah and Ezekiel referred to David because David is a type of the Messiah, in other words, he resembled and foreshadowed the Messiah in certain significant ways. Similarly in Matthew 16 Jesus recognised that Peter's comment was effectively on a par with Satan's temptations to divert him from his mission and Peter was therefore fulfilling a Satanic role.